# Why values in the ArrayList disappeared after using reflection invoke method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two classes:

1. Child class : **receptionist** class with two methods ReadDoctorList(String readLine) and DisplayDoctorList().
2. Parent Class: **base** class with a readLine method where I pass **a method as parameter**, the method is from class receptionist.

My idea is to read from a txt file line by line and extract some lines and store them in an ArrayList. I could print out the values on the fly. **However,the arraylist became empty If I called it from the TestClass.**

Your answer will be greatly appreciated!

```
Output: 
Tonny Bob
Mike tyson
The size is: 0


txt file:
    Tonny,Bob,abc,abc,D
    Mike,tyson,abc,abc,D
    Laura,jack,abc,abc,P
    Jimmy,viva,abc,abc,P
```

---

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
        Receptionist obj = new Receptionist();
        obj.DisplayDoctorList();
        System.out.println("The size is: " + obj.doctorlist.size());
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Base {
    String pathusers = "/Users/MacTonish/users.txt";
    ArrayList<String> doctorlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void readLines(Object instance, String path, Method method)
            throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        try {
            File txt = new File(path);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txt));
            String readLine = null;
            while ((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                method.invoke(instance, readLine); //something is fishy here.
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (

        IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Receptionist extends Base {

    public void DisplayDoctorList() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Method method = Receptionist.class.getMethod("ReadDoctorList", String.class);
        readLines(new Receptionist(), pathusers, method);
    }

    public void ReadDoctorList(String readLine) {
        String[] token = readLine.split(",");
        if (token[4].equals("D")) {
            doctorlist.add(token[0] + " " + token[1]);   
            System.out.println(token[0] + " " + token[1]); //Print out is ok.
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make below changes to your code of Receptionist , it should work

```
    //readLines(new Receptionist(), pathusers, method);

    //Here you are creating a new object but while printing you are using last created Object of ReceptionList
```

Change the above code of line to

```
readLines(this, pathusers, method);
```